# How to create a type based on an objects keys?

Tags: typescript

I have an object with constants. How can I create a type to require pass value specifically from this object, not a string value. So far I managed to create type of the object's values, but it can pass strings as well. See the code snippets too see what I'm trying to achieve. Is it even possible? Thanks.

```
const MY_CONSTANTS = {
  A: 'a',
  B: 'b',
  C: 'c'
}

type MyConstant = '...' // A type here

function doSomething(value: MyConstant) {
  // Do something
}

// I want to allow this kind of expression only
doSomething(MY_CONSTANTS.A);

// And this should be forbiden
doSomething('a')
```

Comment: This seems like something that might be better suited to a linter rather than TypeScript, since what you really care about is the source of the value, not its type.

Comment: `type MyConstant = typeof MY_CONSTANTS[keyof typeof MY_CONSTANTS]`. But you will need to cast either `MY_CONSTANTS` or every its value to `const` for this to work (either `const MY_CONSTANTS = {...} as const` or `const MY_CONSTANTS = {A: 'a' as const, ...}`)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a perfect use case for a pattern called [Branded Types](https://egghead.io/blog/using-branded-types-in-typescript). The concept is simple: You take any type (here, the strings `"a"`, `"b"` `"c"`) and intersect them with another type that has no overlap with anything else. One usually uses the special type [`unique symbol`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html) for that because - as the name implies - they are unique and therefore not comparable to each other.

```
declare const __brand: unique symbol;
type Brand<B> = {[__brand]: B};

const MY_CONSTANTS = {
  A: "a" as unknown as Brand<"a">,
  B: "b" as unknown as Brand<"b">,
  C: "c" as unknown as Brand<"c">
};

type MyConstant = (typeof MY_CONSTANTS)[keyof typeof MY_CONSTANTS];

function doSomething(value: MyConstant) {}

doSomething(MY_CONSTANTS.A);
doSomething("a");
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyConstant'.
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gfWwIxihWAC54BXFASwEdyE0BPAWzyQgG4AoDRgBwQAhQsQA8ggHzwAvPADeAbVwEiwALplBAX25dk6LAFkAmtgDCAeQByAZQAqAQSt2bM%20V3jwHZAERQf8FBoFCgA1ihIAO4ogcHCqqJ%20PhIANB7wgr54AUEh4VExufFiPtmp6Wa%20YDnBlPnRsRkiwInVElw6XDz8CIaMZqiYRFiyABS8AkgAZvAm5tb2Ti4AlAqhIIzT8BMgW3OWto7ONmq6U5RgGFSo8MBINkjMIBgAFlQoAOajAG5QEPRkPoDAzDZbyLRdO4PJ6vd5ffYLI4uAB0DmW3Chj2eb0%20oyS6K4AHpCV4YB9yE8UFgtjt4AByTAwOF0%20BUYIRLBBNBUD4oKB4CAIDBIeB8WBQGEgGDwGk9elAwYYYZ05FAA)